# Not returning any data from ms access database through C#,the Same query if i run on ms access it will fetch the data

Tags: c#, ms-access

Query="Select * from temp8"

Now My table(temp8) Consist of One Record

When I run through C# code in Visual Studio 2017(VS2017) then its returning null
if i take that query and run in ms access directly its picking up the data

i debugged i could not found any issue

If there is 2 record in my table(temp8) and i run in VS2017 it will pick 2nd record

If there is 3 or more record in my table(temp8) and i run in VS2017 it will pick all record that means it picking First Record that previously not taken By VS2017

i Don't know what to do now?

Comment: how can you expect help with no code?

Comment: Look above query= “select *  from temp8”

Comment: This is my code i wrote on my vs2017 but in return m getting null

Comment: No. Thats 1 sql statement. We need your c# code because otherwise there no context. Read how to ask and the whole minimal viable code stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for that

Guys here what is happening is 
Durning pipe lining process

The processor is try to fetch the data before that writing inside a database

So solution

Stall is 
That means

Thread.sleep(1000)